# Why get the data in a variable?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I have the following grapql schema:

```
type Mutation {
    registryUrl(url: UrlInput!): Boolean
}

input UrlInput {
  url: String!
  date: Date!
  name: String!
}
```

And the following code for the resolver:

```
 registryUrl: async (urlInput: IUrlInput) => {
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(urlInput))
```

When I execute the query with a client like this:
**Query**

```
mutation($url: UrlInput!) {
  registryUrl (url: $url)
}
```

**Variables**

```
{"url":{
        "date": "{ 'year': 2020, 'month': 2, 'day': 2 }",
        "url": "localhost",
        "name":"ana"
        }
}
```

In the node app I get the following data:

```
{"url": {"url":"localhost","date":"{ 'year': 2020, 'month': 2, 'day': 2 }","name":"ana"}}
```

Instead of:

```
{"url":"localhost","date":"{ 'year': 2020, 'month': 2, 'day': 2 }","name":"ana"}
```

How can I only get the content of url, in order to avoid to create a new Interfaz?

**Edit:**

The server-side library is express-graphql

Thanks

Comment: 4 standard resolver args?

Comment: I don't follow you

Comment: what tutorial/example you're following?

Comment: I am not following any tutorial, only I picked code from diferent sources.

Comment: better start from sth working ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#handling-arguments

Comment: still valid (for majority of implementations), read these docs